# Search: Same Phrase. Many Alternative meanings

Tags: search, user-research, tooltips, faceted-search, features

Is there a way/tool/ search engine that would allow me to search for multiple variations of the same phrase at the same time?

For example, I want to search for "revealing his true belief". But I also want to search for all the phrases that have the same or similar meaning like"betraying  their real opinion".

The total number of words here is eight but there are many different ways to combine the words so there are many different potential alternative phrases: "revealing his true opinion" "revealing his real opinion"  "betraying our real opinion" etc….

Is there a way to accomplish this in two conditions?

1-  I determine the alternatives. So I specify that for "word 1, word 2, word 3, word 4", the alternatives for word 1 are: Only revealing or showing.

2-  Use all the possible synonyms or even antonyms for "revealing" in word 1.
A very useful tip I got is the use of asterisk so "revealing * true opinion" would yield "revealing your true opinion" and "revealing their true opinion". 
Regards,
Hashem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about User Experience. However, I believe you're looking for something like [Google Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search).

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way? Yes. If you (or someone) tags the relevant articles or associates the relevant search terms.

Large retail companies do this all the time to deal with customer misspellings or alternate names.  For instance if a company sees that Canon is often misspelled as Cannon then these search terms are associated with each other.

Now, if you're asking if search engines' algorithm have a grasp of the English language fine enough to distinguish between

> "revealing his true opinion" and "betraying our real opinion"

well, I haven't seen that anywhere. It will take a while before algorithms (machine learning as applied to language) gets to that point.